# Create a textbox filter on a continuous form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am attempting to filter a form utilizing a textbox. the code I have culled from Stack Overflow is show below.

I have attempted to use this on the OnKeyUp event, and on the AfterUpdate event, and on the On Enter event - all to no avail.

I believe I am close - and likely have missed something simple yet crucial in my attempt to enter the appropriate criteria in the proper places in this code.

P.S. - additionally - This form has 39K+ rows of data. I would also like to have the form only show the data requested in the filter, when requested by the filter, if possible.

I attempted a "combo box" solution found in the forums here as well, but the outcome was not what I required.

```
Private Sub txtNameFilter_KeyUp(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
On Error GoTo errHandler

Dim filterText As String

'Apply or update filter based on user input.
If Len(txtNameFilter.Text) > 0 Then
   filterText = txtNameFilter.Text
   Me.Form.Filter = "[CA_StatTimeSearch]![LookupTxtBox] LIKE '*" & filterText & "*'"
   Me.FilterOn = True
  'Retain filter text in search box after refresh.
   txtNameFilter.Text = filterText
   txtNameFilter.SelStart = Len(txtNameFilter.Text)
Else
   ' Remove filter.
   Me.Filter = ""
   Me.FilterOn = False
   txtNameFilter.SetFocus
End If


Exit Sub

errHandler:

MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbOKOnly, "Error ..."
End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: when I type in the requested sort criteria..it just doesn't do *anything*.

Comment: I haven't tried this kind of filter myself, but you are using `Me.Filter` at one point, and ` Me.Form.Filter` at another. Why is that?

Comment: as I have been instructed, the Me.Form.Filter must be in place to allow for the form to be filtered as I type in the name of the unit I am trying to filter to. The second instance, I believe, is the filter for the query on which this report is based.

Comment: I simply need this filter to return all instances of the data associated with the criteria I am typing in to the textbox. I am new to this type of filtering as well...hence the issue.

Comment: I am trying to ask the question and provide pertinent data in order to allow for an efficient solution from the field of experts here. If there are any other conditions I need to provide, please let me know. 

The form is a continuous form, the event procedure is called in the textbox property, the VBA code builder shows the form in the leftmost pane (so I am reasonably certain the VBA Code and the Form is "seen")...

I am at a a loss.